# SAS Macros for plotting

Tags: sas

I'm trying to make some plots. I need to make 19 scatter plots with the names in verf_typ_nmes substituted into the data and proc steps one at a time then executed. I've researched Google and thought I copied correctly but no good.

Errors I'm getting:
"Expected %TO not found in %DO statement"
 ERROR: A dummy macro will be compiled.

```
%macro Multiplot();
  %do verf_typ_nmes =  BDPREP, BRCODE, CONTNT, COPAL, CURSRY,
                       DFTEST,DOCPST,DSMS,LABEL,MAILING,                           
                       MAILPC,MERLIN,MMS,MPCV,PRESRT,PVDS,                                         
                       SHPAID,TAP,WEIGHT;
   data &verf_typ_nmes;
     set vol_verfns_prime;
     where verif_type="&verf_typ_nmes";
   RUN;
   proc sgscatter data=&verf_typ_nmes;
     plot verif_pstg*(t_v tfev mlgs fsp avpm);
   run;
   %end;
 %mend;
```

Answer (score 2):

The `%DO` statement is not as powerful as the `DO` statement.

Why not just use a `BY` statement?

```
proc sgscatter data=vol_verfns_prime;
  by verif_type ;
  where verif_type in ('BDPREP' 'BRCODE' ..... );
  plot verif_pstg*(t_v tfev mlgs fsp avpm);
run;
```

If you do need to loop over a list of names then put the list in a macro variable and use `%scan()` to pull out the values one by one.

```
%let list=
   BDPREP BRCODE CONTNT COPAL CURSRY DFTEST DOCPST DSMS LABEL
   MAILING MAILPC MERLIN MMS MPCV PRESRT PVDS SHPAID TAP WEIGHT
;
%do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&list));
  ...
   where verif_type="%scan(&list,&i)";
  ...
%end;
```

Don't use comma as your delimiter in lists if you can avoid it. Commas will make it harder to use your list in function and macro calls.

Comment: Or at least skip the data step with the where and just put the where in the data set options on `SGSCATTER`... but yes, the `BY` option seems most correct in most use cases.